# Sending bulkemails with java mail takes too long

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have to following situation. I want to send bulk emails with java mail client. This means I want to send a lot of emails at once. The opinion to put them all together in the recipient field is out of question because no recipient have to see each other (bcc doesn't work, because you still see the to-recipient).
So what I do is, open a new `Transport` connection, use `sendMessage()` for every single recipient and close `Transport` connection afterwards. Here is the code snippet:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(smtpProps, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPass);
    }
});

InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(eml, "UTF-8");
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, is);

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(smtpServer, smtpPort, smtpUser, smtpPass);

Address[] recipients = message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO);
for(Address address : recipients) {
    message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, address);
    transport.sendMessage(message, new Address[]{ address });
}
transport.close();
```

Remember that the `sendMessage()` method is an abstract method of the `javax.mail.Transport` class and so the implementation of the `SMTPTransport` from the `com.sun.mail.smtp` is used in my case.

No to my problem: The connection time at `transport.connect()` takes about 5 seconds, the sending time at `sendMessage` too. This means, if I send emails to, for example, 10 recipients, it takes 5 + (10*5) = ~55 seconds. This is to long, think about when we have 1000 recipients.

Is this normal and okay? Or do you have any idea what can cause the problem, that it tooks this long time? Is there any other (good) `sendMessage()` implementation, or is `SMTPTransport` the default usage for this method?

**Information:**
The for-loop, respectively, this code snipped runs in a seperate thread, so the emails are send in background. And the whole servlet, which contains this snipped, runs in a docker-container on a servercluster. So if i parallelise this, or use multiple threads, i don't know how the behaviour is in concurence with other servlets on this cluster.

Comment: Have you tried to parallelise this? I understand that this is a whole method with some parameters, such as the `authUser`and `authPass`and the email body `eml` (?) 

Seems quite easy to do. Just try to call this method from a thread pool executor or with the java 8 `parallelStream()` lambda. Here there are plenty of exampes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

Comment: In fact you could try to change the `for` loop with a `parallelStream()` that should do it.

Comment: @Marc: Yes this is only a snipped from a bigger method. This loop already runs in a seperate thread, so that the emails are send in background. And this whole servlet runs in a docker container in a cluster. I don't know how the behavior in concurence with other servlets there is, if I have a lot of threads, this could cause problems, i don't know exactly. I expand my question with this information.

Comment: DNS lookup can hurt performance on some machines.  Set the session property for `mail.smtp.localhost` to prevent name lookup on the `HELO` command.  Set session property for `mail.from` or `mail.host` (not the protocol versions) as that will prevent the name lookup on `MimeMessage.updateMessageID()`.

Comment: Did you see this [JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#rptsend)?

Comment: Yes this is what i do already, as you can see in my code.
My problem was on another point in my implementation. I answered my question already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think i found a solution for my problem.
That the connect takes so much time seems to be normal.
My problem was, that the attachment had to be uploaded to the smtp-server everytime, about 4 seconds. Every single upload sums up to a very large amount of time for the whole request.
So without sending attachments, the requests didn't take so much time. So there is no problem in my implementation, rather than uploading attachments every time.

Comment: you should think for a larger picture, like what if you really needed to upload or download a big eml file ?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using:

```
Address[] recipients = message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO);
for(Address address : recipients) {
    message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, address);
    transport.sendMessage(message, new Address[]{ address });
}
```

You should use:

```
Address[] recipients = message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO);
message.addRecipients(RecipientType.CC, recipients);
```

This will send a single request to the mail server for the mail and will save a lot of time and requests.

Comment: No i can't. Please read my whole question and not only the code-part. Please read the 4th sentence and  then you know why your answer is not the answer to my problem.